# Correctly escaping backslash in python

Tags: python, escaping

I know, it's probably a super easy problem with tons of answers here. I tried to read around but I can't find a solution to this.

I know that the backslash `\` is a special character and that to escape it, I need to double it like `\\`.

I want to create a string with a file name pointing to a different folder, something like `fld\filename.mat`. But this string is a concatenation of the `filename` given by a `var_filename` with the folder name and the file extension as strings. I then use this variable to load a file into python.

I tried `var = 'fld\\' + var_filename + '.mat'` but then, when I try to use it to load the file, it tells me it cannot find
`fld\\filename.mat`.

While of course if I try `var = 'fld\' + var_filename + '.mat'`, it gives me an end-of-line error `EOL while scanning string literal` because I believe `\'` it's seen as the escape for the `'`.

Thanks for your help

Comment: How exactly do you test “what it gives you”?

Comment: I actually use var to load a file into python and it just tells me that it can't find a file called `fld\\...`

Comment: What makes you think a slash needs escaping, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you provide input and required output?

Comment: Because this is XY problem, OP actually wants to create file path - there are plenty of other and better ways to do this - raw string, forward slash, `os.path.join()` or `pathlib.PurePath.joinpath()` method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be useful for your problem, concatenation is safe and you can check whether the specific file exists.

```py
import os

filename = 'filename'
ext = '.txt'
folder = 'folder

var = os.path.join(folder, filename + ext)
exists = os.path.isfile(var)
```

Comment: I tried but it apparently doesn't work. This is what I did: `print(file_imu)` which gives this output `007Figure8` and then `file_imu = os.path.join('IMU', file_imu + '.mat')`, followed by the loading command `imu = sp.loadmat(file_imu)` which ends in error `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'IMU\\007Figure8.mat'`

Comment: What is the result of the os.path.isfile(path_to_file) call? The path you are using is relative to your current working directory. This might be the reason why the file is not found.

Comment: So if I put a print before the loadmat command I actually get the correct path. I guess therefore it's rather the loadmat command that is weirdly escaping that backslash character...

Comment: See my first reply. Additionaly, there shouldn't be any problems concerning the backslash when using os.path.join().

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple variables with different parts of the path, you can concatenate them all into one.

```
parent_folder = "parent_folder"
folder = "folder"
name = "file"
ext = ".py"
path = parent_folder + "\\" + folder + "\\" + name + ext
print(path)
```